# Simple AWS Lambda Terraform plan fails with ValidationException Error 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to apply the belowmentioned terraform plan, but it fails with a validation error.

I wrote a python function that exists in the dir `lambda_function/sns_to_slack.py`, I am zipping it through terraform and uploading it to AWS.

I get this error:

`error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException:  status code: 400`

**File:** `aws_lambda.tf`

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
    type          = "zip"
    source_file   = "lambda_functions/sns_to_slack.py"
    output_path   = "lambda_functions/zips/sns_to_slack.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "sns_to_slack" {
  filename         = "lambda_functions/zips/sns_to_slack.zip"
  function_name    = "sns_to_slack"
  role             = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_tf.arn
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256
  runtime          = "python3.8"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda_tf" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda_tf"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Any ideas what is up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specififed your **handler** as you use non-default file name (`sns_to_slack.py`):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "sns_to_slack" {
  filename         = "lambda_functions/zips/sns_to_slack.zip"
  function_name    = "sns_to_slack"
  
  handler          = "sns_to_slack.lambda_handler"
  
  role             = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_tf.arn
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256
  runtime          = "python3.8"
}
```

`lambda_handler` in `"sns_to_slack.lambda_handler"` must be changed to what you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks! Just for the context: What is the default handler name?

Comment: @Dimitris It is `lambda_function.lambda_handler`.